# @Autowired Repository in ConstraintValidator null when used from CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up a Spring-Data-Rest App using Spring Boot *1.5.9.RELEASE*. I have a `ConstraintValidator` set up like this:

`UniqueEmail.java`:

```java
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {UniqueEmailValidator.class})
@NotNull
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface UniqueEmail {

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    String message() default "{eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.validation.UniqueEmail.message}";

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    static @interface List {
        UniqueEmail[] value();
    }

}
```

`UniqueEmailValidator.java`:

```java
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.repository.AccountRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueEmail annotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return accountRepository.findByEmail(email) == null;
    }

}
```

I've also set up listeners for the `beforeCreate` and `beforeSave` repository methods:

`RestConfiguration.java`:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.event.ValidatingRepositoryEventListener;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", localValidatorFactoryBean());
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", localValidatorFactoryBean());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

**My problem:**

The validator seems to work when the repository methods are called through REST endpoints, however I also try to set up some stuff in the connected database via a `CommandLineRunner` that uses the same repository. When the calls to the repository are validated, the autowired `AccountRepository` in the `ConstraintValidator` is `null` even if it isn't null at the same time in the CommandLineRunner that also has the same repository autowired. I don't understand this.

Does anybody have an idea why the repository is null when the validation is triggered from the CommandLineRunner?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Daniel

*Edit: added the CommandLineRunner Code*

`InitAdminData.java`:

```java
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.entity.Account;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.entity.AccountDetails;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.entity.AccountProfile;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.entity.Client;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.enumeration.AccountRoles;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.enumeration.ClientRoles;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.enumeration.GrantTypes;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.repository.AccountRepository;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.repository.ClientRepository;
import eu.icarus.momca.backend.domain.service.AccountService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

@Component
public class InitAdminData implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Collection<AccountRoles> DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ROLES = Arrays.asList(AccountRoles.ROLE_ACCOUNT, AccountRoles.ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR, AccountRoles.ROLE_CLIENT_OWNER);

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitAdminData.class);

    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    private AccountService accountService;

    @Value("${app.admin-email}")
    private String adminEmail;

    @Value("${app.admin-name}")
    private String adminName;

    @Value("${app.admin-password}")
    private String adminPassword;

    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Value("${app.default-client-description}")
    private String defaultClientDescription;

    @Autowired
    public InitAdminData(AccountRepository accountRepository, AccountService accountService, ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    private Account initAdminAccount() {
        Account adminAccount = accountRepository.findByAccountProfile_Name(adminName);
        if (adminAccount == null) {
            adminAccount = new Account();
            logger.info("Initialized new admin account");
        } else {
            logger.info("Refreshed admin account");
        }
        setAdminAccountData(adminAccount);
        return accountService.save(adminAccount, adminPassword);
    }

    private void initDefaultClient(Account adminAccount) {
        long adminAccountId = adminAccount.getId();
        Collection<Client> adminClients = clientRepository.findAllByOwnerId(adminAccountId);
        if (adminClients.isEmpty()) {
            Client defaultClient = new Client();
            defaultClient.setOwnerId(adminAccountId);
            defaultClient.setDescription(defaultClientDescription);
            Collection<ClientRoles> clientRoles = new HashSet<>(2);
            clientRoles.add(ClientRoles.ROLE_CLIENT);
            clientRoles.add(ClientRoles.ROLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT);
            defaultClient.setRoles(clientRoles);
            Collection<GrantTypes> grantTypes = new HashSet<>();
            grantTypes.add(GrantTypes.authorization_code);
            grantTypes.add(GrantTypes.client_credentials);
            grantTypes.add(GrantTypes.password);
            grantTypes.add(GrantTypes.refresh_token);
            defaultClient.setGrantTypes(grantTypes);
            defaultClient = clientRepository.save(defaultClient);
            logger.info(String.format("Added new default client with id '%s'", defaultClient.getId()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        Account adminAccount = initAdminAccount();
        initDefaultClient(adminAccount);
    }

    private void setAdminAccountData(Account adminAccount) {
        adminAccount.setEmail(adminEmail);
        adminAccount.setRoles(DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ROLES);
        adminAccount.setAccountDetails(new AccountDetails());
        adminAccount.setAccountProfile(new AccountProfile(adminName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like the components where not initialized on startup when using the CommandLineRunner. Please try annotating the class that was started using the CommandLineRunner with `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Please share your code/class that was started using the CommandLineRunner

Comment: Thanks for your reply @alltej ! I've edited the question to add the CommandLineRunner.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@ComponentScan` annotation.

```
@ComponentScan
public class InitAdminData implements CommandLineRunner {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to work. Replacing `@Component` with `@ComponentScan` makes it not being picked up by Spring boot and adding `@Component` additionally makes it behave as before.

Comment: Can you add/have both annotations and see it if works?

Comment: I did. There doesn't seem to be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have few cases :-

1. you haven't autowired your service and Repo
2. you haven't scan your Repo where you have your service and Repo.
3. Or you haven't use @Component(any stereotype) annotation on your classes which you are autowiring

Comment: Hi, outside the CommandLineRunner the service and repository are picked up just fine, it just seems as if somehow the application context is different in the commandline runner. I also just now noticed that events like `@HandleBeforeSave` don't seem to be fired during the commandline runner but work just fine after the Startup is finished. I would like to know why that is so.